# Do we reopen post marked as duplicate, where the link leads to a dead-end

Tags: discussion

I was just searching around to find similar posts to a question to make sure I'm not putting an effort to answer something which is already there. However, when I was going through; found an interesting post which is marked as duplicated and the link leads to a dead-end leaving the user nowhere.

- [**How to Access Webmin? [duplicate]**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/384609/how-to-access-webmin)

Are such questions reopened expecting an answer (quite sure OP won't be around as his last seen shows up somewhere in 2013) or just leave as is since it is an old post.

I'm not sure such a clarification has been asked. If so, please do comment.

Comment: From the comment on that post, it's a fair bet the duplicate was also posted by the same user.

Comment: I'm not sure, whether you're making a guess or strong on that opinion as you have experience than me. But what would happen to such question? Will this be just left along?

Comment: If you're still interested in this, there's a discussion over on [meta.se]: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272406/270345

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dupe was also posted by the same poster. It has no answer, so nothing of value was lost by its deletion, which happened *a month* after the closure. We could reopen the post, by I see no value from doing so - unless somebody has an answer to post.

Interestingly, the dupe was posted after this post, and after the answer it had was posted. So the OP wasn't satisfied by the answer.

[image]

Comment: Strange though! I'll go with your instincts since it pretty much proves everything was for a reason. Thanks for the screenshot..